# Character encoding-decoding json payload string in Requests HTTP library

Tags: json, python-2.7, request

I am using Requests HTTP library. I am trying to simple print HTML of the requested page.

Here is my payload string, I tried with decode('utf-8') but it doesn't work:

```
import json
import requests

url = "http://ec.europa.eu/eures/eures-searchengine/page/jvSearch/search?lang=de&app=1.3.1p1-build-0"

countryName = "ÖSTERREICH".decode('utf-8')

payload = '{"keywords":[{"keyword":"","specificSearchCode":"EVERYWHERE"}],"locationCriteriaBean":{"selectedNuts":[{"id":1231,"nutsCode":"AT","parentNutsId":None,"countryId":1,"label":"%s","nutsLevel":0,"regions":[]}],"notSpecifiedInCountry":[]},"selectedOccupations":[],"contractTypeCodes":[],"contractDurationCodes":[],"experienceCodes":[],"educationLevelCodes":[],"euresFlagCodes":[],"page":1,"resultsPerPage":50,"publicationDate":"LAST_MONTH","sortSearch":"REPLICATION_DATE_DESCENDING"}'% countryName

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print r.status_code
```

I am getting 500. Can some one tell me what should I do for that?

Comment: Why do you think it's your job to handle `unicode`s? And why are you dumping JSON in a string as JSON?

Comment: I tried with `unicode("ÖSTERREICH")` but it returns an error..... This is a JSON string so I am dumping it.

Comment: No, that's not a JSON string, that's a string that contains JSON. And that's not how you specify a `unicode` literal.

Comment: hm... you are right!

Comment: I removed `json.dumps` but the problem is still there